# How to set Icon for JSP or Servlet Web App

Tags: java, jsp, web, servlets, icons

I know that we need to put this line of code in a HTML page for having an icon (corner of the website).

```html
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="fav.ico" />
```

but if i have many JSP(s) and Servlet(s), is there any simple way instead of put that line of code into every single page of JSP(s) or even Servlet(s)?

Answer (score 2):

The common way is that you write some codes as header and import it in all jsp pages like this:

```
<%@ include file="/common/header.jsp"%>
```

There are other decoration frameworks like [sitemesh](https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh3) which you can create template page with lots of abilities for your hole website.

Comment: alright then, so basically we need to put that in every page. There's no put 1 into config and they do it automatically for the rest..... :D

Comment: @gumuruh as I told frameworks like sitemesh will do something like that for you